# Counting sequences with parity constraints on occurrences

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Given positive integers $n,m,s,t$ with $s\leq t\leq m$, I want to count the number of (ordered) sequences of length $n$ whose values are integers in $[1,m]$ with the following restrictions:

- each of the values $1,2,3,...,s$ appear an even number of times (possibly zero)
- each of the values $s+1,s+2,...,t$ appear an odd number of times
- there's no constraint on the values $t+1,t+2,...,m$

Is there an easy approach to compute this? I could only deduce that the number is $n!$ times the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$\left(\cosh^{s} x\right) \left(\sinh^{t-s} x\right) \left(\exp^{m-t} x\right)$$
but that's not very helpful computationally.

Comment: actually, the coefficient of your expression is the number of not ordered lists, and multiplying by $n!$ is not the right things to do, since there are repetitions

Comment: @Exodd the repetitions should get handled because all the terms are of form $\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$, so whenever we multiply by some $x^k$ we also divide that $n!$ by $k!$.

Comment: In that case, you are counting the number of not-ordered lists

Comment: @Exodd can you please elaborate on that? I can't really see how that counts unordered lists. If a list contains $n=a+b+c$ elements where $a,b,c$ are the frequencies of $1,2,3$ then there are $\dfrac{n!}{a!b!c!}$ ordered lists from them, right?